# How do I fix my my table so I don't get that the invalid datatype message?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table in SQL and every time it I get the following error message:

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

```
SQL> create table BUSINESS (
  2  B_IDINTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  3  B_CITYchar(20) not null,
  4  B_NAMECHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  5  B_CATEGORY(S) CHAR (25),
  6  B_ACCTCHAR (25)
  7  );
B_CITYchar(20) not null,
          *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

It is supposed to say table created but I don't know what is wrong with line 3.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  `(20)` is not a valid type in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code.  Try something like this:

```
create table BUSINESS (
  B_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  B_CITY varchar2(20) not null,
  B_NAME varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
  B_CATEGORY varchar2(25),
  B_ACCT varchar2(25)
);
```

Note that you should generally use variable length strings unless you know the value has a fixed length (which might be true of `b_acct` but is not true for `b_city`).